# When do continous functions preserve retracts?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a continous function $f: X \to Y$ , what conditions are required such that a retract $A$ of $X$ is mapped to a retract $B$ of $Y$? That is, a retraction from $Y$ to $f(A)$ exists.

This is a problem I came up with, but seems a bit beyond my weightclass..

Comment: Can you think of any necessary conditions for retracts that are not preserved by general continuous maps?

Comment: Hmm I mean, one point is that the retraction map from $f(A)$ to $Y$ may have no relation to how the traction map works on $X$. So...

Comment: There's no mapping from functions $A\to A$ to functions $B\to B$.

Comment: @JohnDoe retracts are preserved under isomorphisms, so the set of functions, for which the question makes sense, is nonempty...

Comment: @JonasLinssen: I think you mean homeomorphisms :)

Comment: So you cannot think of any property satisfied by all retracts in Hausdorff spaces.....

Comment: They are closed @MoisheKohan

Comment: Excellent. Now, do continuous maps of Hausdorff spaces always map closed subsets to closed subsets?

Comment: Just to be precise: you ask what continuous functions map every retract to retract?

Comment: I am not sure.. @MoisheKohan

Comment: @freakish I think so. Is there an ambiguity in the question?

Comment: So the necessary condition is for $f$ to be a closed map (not every continuous map is closed). But that is not sufficient: the projection $\pi:[0,1]^3\to[0,1]^2$ is closed but it will map a spiral into circle.

Comment: Another counterexample: if $X$ discrete then this means that the image of $f$ has to consist of isolated points (isolated in the image). I think under mild assumptions on $Y$ (Hausdorff + connected) this means $f$ has to be constant . In other words I think it will be pretty rare for $f$ to have such property.